# Three.js - How to rotate Object from it's own perspective?

Tags: javascript, three.js

Let's say I have a simple object (not added to scene)

```
var object = new THREE.Object3D;
//simple X rotation
object.rotation.x += 0.1;
```

Now I'm trying to rotate it on the `y` axis, from the object's perspective

```
//doesn't rotate y properly, since x has been rotated
object.rotation.y += 0.1;
```

It appears since the `x` axis has been rotated, the `rotation.y` rotates the object from a different point

How do I rotate the `object` from the object's perspective?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you the object is rotating from a different point? not on the origin point?

Comment: @UdaraSampath no matter what ways the object has been rotated, I need the rotation of x y and z to rotate the object the same exact way. Let's say I have a cylinder --  the y rotation would turn it left/right, the z rotation would flip it up and down. When I rotate a specific way, the rotation methods change and y rotation doesn't turn it left/right anymore

Comment: Are you sure the model has the same axes orientation as the Three js. Try adding this code and see what way the axes are in. `scene.add(new THREE.AxesHelper(500));`

Comment: @UdaraSampath the object is a blank and isn't added to a scene, it's used only for calculation purposes. The rotations should occur based on which way the object is pointing, so up is always up, down - down, ect,  from it's perspective